# ssh to localhost

Tags: macos, ssh

I am following some steps from a wiki to install Hadoop, Cloudera, etc...

One of the steps is saying "ssh to localhost"  and make sure you don't get a pass phrase,
I was getting pass phrase indeed, but wiki has some steps to run and fix that.

Now when I ssh to localhost, this is the output I see.  But I have no experience in these things, is it the correct output I should see after running that command?

```
➜  ~  ssh localhost
Last login: Wed Mar 27 08:41:18 2013 from localhost
```

Is that it?

And if I do the debug mode this is what I get:

```
➜  ~  sshd -Dd
sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path
```

I am also on OSX 10.8

Comment: This is an error: ***`sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path`***. You should not be seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the first command, that is the output you should see.

```
➜  ~  ssh localhost
Last login: Wed Mar 27 08:41:18 2013 from localhost
```

Comment: what output? you haven't posted it :)

Comment: No, but you have :) : `Last login: Wed Mar 27 08:41:18 2013 from localhost`

Comment: @user112551 See edit :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to test whether or not the SSH server is running and accepting logins. If this is the case, then the message you are getting is the right one.

If SSH is not running, you will get something like:

```
~ ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Also, it is unnecesary to start the SSH service via the Terminal on OS X. Use System Preferences->Sharing and check off "Remote Login". There are a few settings here you can mess with but the defaults should be fine for most cases.

**Update**

Forgot to mention about the passphrase. Passphrase is not used by default. Whether or not you need it depends on what you are trying to accomplish, so you'll have to be more specific on the situation (a link to the article you are reading might be a good start). :)